# Create a new git repo from a local folder

Tags: github, gitlab

I have a directory on my laptop and it is not empty. I would like to save it into GitLab's clouds in a new repository m how to do that?

Comment: Please, have a look on it https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/intro/ . You can find your answers with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Create repo on Gitlab, clone that repo on your PC, copy your project to that cloned repo. 
Commit -> Push.

Answer (score 0):

Simply push the project to create a new one, as per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project

> This can be done by using either SSH or HTTPS:
>
> ```
> ## Git push using SSH
> git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
>
> ## Git push using HTTPS
> git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.example.com/namespace/nonexistent-project.git master`
> ```
>
> Once the push finishes successfully, a remote message will indicate
>   the command to set the remote and the URL to the new project:
>
> ```
> remote: remote: The private project namespace/nonexistent-project was created. 
> remote: 
> remote: To configure the remote, run: 
> remote:   git remote add origin https://gitlab.example.com/namespace/nonexistent-project.git remote:
> remote: To view the project, visit: 
> remote:   https://gitlab.example.com/namespace/nonexistent-project 
> remote:
> ```